# Stasheff's proof of non-existence of $A_p$ structures on some spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading now J. Stasheff's "Homotopy Associativity of H-Spaces, I":
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993608.
I have following problem with Theorem 17, part of proof where it is shown that constructed space does not admit $A_p$-structure. It is written that

> Thus we know that the Thom-Gysin sequence applies to the "Thom space", $C\mathcal{E}_i\cup_{\mathcal{p}_i}\mathcal{B}_i=XP(i)$. (...) In exactly the same way (as in real and complex projective spaces), since $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}_p)=H^*(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1};\mathbb{Z}_p)$, we find that $H^*({XP(i);\mathbb{Z}_p})$ is a truncated polynomial algebra on a generator $u\in H^{2n}(XP(i);\mathbb{Z}_p)$ with $u^i\neq 0$.

I don't get it. In order to use the Thom-Gysin sequence or the Serre Spectral Sequence we have to know something about cohomology of total space, $\mathcal{E}_i$ in Stasheff's notation. We know that $\mathcal{E}_i$ is homotopy equivalent to $i$-fold join of $X$, and that $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}_p)=H^*(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1};\mathbb{Z}_p)$. How can we show that $H^*(XP(i);\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is truncated polynomial algebra?

Comment: Note that $H^*(X)$ is a CW complex with the bottom cell in dimension $2n-1$. The inclusion of the bottom cell $i:S^{2n-1}\hookrightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism on $H_*$, and thus on $\pi_*$ since both spaces are simply connected. Thus $i$ is a p-local equivalence. It follows that $H^*(\mathcal{E}_i)\cong H^*(S^{2ni-1})$, and we use the same techniques to calculate $H^*(XP(i))$ as we do real or complex projective $i$-space.

Comment: Why do you claim, that $X$ has only one bottom-dimension cell? As far as I understand construction of a Moor space, in that case group is not finitely generated, so the Moor space of this group have infinitely many bottom-dimension cells.

Comment: We are working $p$-locally so really it has one $p$-local cell. You can either localise all spaces and maps at the prime $p$, or just concentrate on using homological arguments with appropriate coefficients. (Stasheff uses Serre's $\mathcal{C}$-theory which is more or less equivalent to localisation for the spaces in question.)